# Why doesnt the isClosed() method return true for PreparedStatements if the underlying connection is closed?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Just as the title says, I was wondering why a prepared statements .isClosed() method will return false after closing the underlying stream (Using JDBC).

```
public void someTest() throws SQLException, InterruptedException {
    Connection conn = DBHelper.newConnection();
    PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareCall(CLEANUP_DELETE);

    conn.close();

    System.out.println(statement.isClosed());

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println(statement.isClosed());
}
```

Output

```
false
false
```

But if you attempt to invoke a set method or an execute you get this:

```
java.sql.SQLException: org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingCallableStatement with address: "SQLServerCallableStatement:32" is closed.
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.checkOpen(DelegatingStatement.java:137)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setInt(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:120)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setInt(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:120)
at com.ipti.ptl.common.messagetable.MessageHandlerTest.someTest(MessageHandlerTest.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) .....
```

Comment: Perhaps the PreparedStatement could still be used once you open another new connection.

Comment: I don't quite understand, the PreparedStatement is constructed from a connection. If I recreate the connection, then prepare a statement.. isn't it distinct from the first prepared statement?

Comment: @ErwinSmout Good point but how? `PreparedStatement` has no `setConnection` method...

Comment: Simply new Connection().executePreparedStatement(previouslyPreparedStatement) ?

Comment: Your title and your question aren't the same. Closing the connection does indeed close the PreparedStatement. The JDBC Specification says so, and your exception proves it. Your question is about why PreparedStatement.isClosed() doesn't say so, in some specific implementation.

Comment: Sure ill give ya that EJP, but you would think that .isClosed() would tell you if the statement was closed, which it clearly doesn't. it tells you if someone called the .close() method..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a bug with the DBCP library, although I would have to look at the JDBC spec. Have you tried using native JDBC `PreparedStatement` for your driver?

**EDIT**:

Looking at the MySQL connector source code (available [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/)) it looks like the implementation of `Connection.close()` actually closes all the statements associated with the connection. So when using the MySQL JDBC driver, `PreparedStatement.isClosed()` **will** return true if the connection was closed. I am not quite sure what the JDBC specification says about this though.

In your case, I am not sure if the DBCP library is delegating the call to `isClosed()` to the underlying driver or not, that's why I recommend removing this extra layer and see what happens. If there is a bug in DBCP, I would report it. If there is a bug in the underlying driver you are using, I would report that too. Assuming this would be a bug indeed.

**EDIT 2**:

Per the comments, the JDBC 4.1 specification says (section 9.4.4.1):

> Connection.close
>
> An application calls the method Connection.close() to indicate that it has
>   finished using a connection. All Statement objects created from a given
>   Connection object will be closed when the close method for the Connection
>   object is called.

So I would expect the statement to be indeed closed. So there is a bug either in the DBCP library or the MS SQL Server driver in use.

Comment: Am am using JDBC, Ive tagged it, but ill mention it explicitly in the question for clarification.

Comment: That's not what I meant. You are using Apache Commons DBCP (according to the stack trace) that wraps the JDBC driver. Which actual driver are you using?

Comment: org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDriver

Comment: Again, you are not getting my point: the exception you are seeing is being thrown by DBCP, I understand that. However, the underlying JDBC driver might or might not throw in this scenario. Thus, it might be a bug in DBCP. Which actual database are you using?

Comment: a MS SQL Server 2012 : jdbc:apache:commons:dbcp: Forgive me if I misunderstood again, not quite sure what your asking...

Comment: You know that the Apache DBCP is just a wrapper for the actual JDBC driver right? Meaning DBCP can __not__ actually connect to any database, it requires the database's native JDBC driver to work?

Comment: I did not write the logic to create the DB connections. I was only aware we were using jdbc, and didn't know we used apache dbcp as a wrapper until this was pointed out from the stack trace.

Comment: As a quick note, I didn't not find any references to Preparedstatement.isClosed() anywhere in the JDBC spec available at http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.oracle.com%2Fotn-pub%2Fjcp%2Fjdbc-4_1-mrel-spec%2Fjdbc4.1-fr-spec.pdf&ei=1Z5FU_vlKqTLsASq2oIw&usg=AFQjCNFlFM4LMw6drZdIuq750mcF4EvIkA&sig2=ss8IWVMr_a-1nsLQARlyoA

Comment: Thank you Giovanni for investigating this. I appreciate it. I'll explore around with what I have to see if I can make this happen, and report it as a bug if necessary.

Comment: Actually looking at the JDBC specification was a great pointer. Calling `Connection.close()` should close all the statements. I updated my answer.